# Compiling demo/final versions of android application for Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Right now I've finished an application that I want to distribute on Android Market.
It will have a payed version and a free version with some limited features.
While developing it, I was doing obviously just the main project of fully featured release. And now after finished I've included a "boolean" DEMO_VERSION=true that restrict those features.

My question is if it's possible to generate both apk from the same project? Or should I create new project with the same source but changing the java package to tell android market that they're two different applications.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good article on exactly that question: http://ulrichscheller.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-deploying-multiple-targets-from.html

Comment: Oh no!  the blog is deleted :(