# multiple package names for the market

Tags: android, build, packaging

I'm writing an applications and I want two version's of it on the market, 
the first would be a trial version, and the second is a full version.

I wanted to ask what is the best way to have it as 2 package names?
If I just change the package name in the manifest I also need to change all the references in my classes, which I rather not do

have anyone here done it before and have any recommendations for me?

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073001/compiling-demo-final-versions-of-android-application-for-android-market

Comment: Use version control and keep 2 branches

Comment: how would 2 branches help me?